# Recommended configuration for my blade servers?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I currently am in possession of 5 blade servers all different specs.  Some are dual core, some aren't.  Some have 2GB of RAM, others 8GB.  Some are running Windows 2000 other Windows Server 2003.

What I have is the option to start fresh with their configuration and install any OS I choose.  It's a learning opportunity for me, so I would like some advice as to how to make these work for a small business.

I was thinking of having these server roles:

- Domain
- Exchange
- Printing
- File sharing

Is clustering the best way?

Comment: As it stands now, your question is awfully open-ended.  You should edit it to detail what your business requirements are.  Without knowing what you *need* to do with these blades, the question is likely to be closed as too subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a very specific need to, don't bother with clustering.

Throw Exchange on the best one, followed by two domain controllers, printing, and file sharing.

If you're just starting to learn about this, read a lot of [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default.aspx) articles. Heck, read everything you can about these services. If you don't feel 100% comfortable with what you're doing, call in a consultant so you can see it done by someone who is.

Comment: Cheers, I am just doing it as a small project to learn from. I will read the technet stuff soon, currently learning asp.net ... Long.